# start timer when button pressed and show timer in text [ matlab ]

Tags: matlab, timer

[when i look this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) 
i really don't know how to implement this timer

i want to create object timer when pushbutton2 pressed and the timer will stop when the process in pussbutton2 is finished

> note : timer will show in text1

here is my code:

```
     function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) global x
        global fs global silenceRemovedSignal THRESHOLD =
        str2double(get(handles.edit1,'String'));

        samplePerFrame=floor(fs/100); bgSampleCount=floor(fs/5); %according
   to formula, 1600 sample needed for 8 khz

   %---------- %calculation of mean and std bgSample=[]; for
   i=1:1:bgSampleCount
       bgSample=[bgSample x(i)]; end meanVal=mean(bgSample); sDev=std(bgSample); %---------- %identify voiced or not for each
   value for i=1:1:length(x)    if(abs(x(i)-meanVal)/sDev > THRESHOLD)
          voiced(i)=1;    else
          voiced(i)=0;    end end


   % identify voiced or not for each frame %discard insufficient samples
   of last frame

   usefulSamples=length(x)-mod(length(x),samplePerFrame);
   frameCount=usefulSamples/samplePerFrame; voicedFrameCount=0; for
   i=1:1:frameCount    cVoiced=0;    cUnVoiced=0;    for
   j=i*samplePerFrame-samplePerFrame+1:1:(i*samplePerFrame)
          if(voiced(j)==1)
              cVoiced=(cVoiced+1);
          else
              cUnVoiced=cUnVoiced+1;
          end    end    %mark frame for voiced/unvoiced    if(cVoiced>cUnVoiced)
          voicedFrameCount=voicedFrameCount+1;
          voicedUnvoiced(i)=1;    else
          voicedUnvoiced(i)=0;    end end


   silenceRemovedSignal=[];

   %----- for i=1:1:frameCount
       if(voicedUnvoiced(i)==1)
       for j=i*samplePerFrame-samplePerFrame+1:1:(i*samplePerFrame)
               silenceRemovedSignal= [silenceRemovedSignal x(j)];
           end
       end end

   global t4 t4=(0:length(silenceRemovedSignal)-1)/fs;
   set(handles.axes2,'HandleVisibility','ON'); axes(handles.axes2); axis
   on;
   plot(t4,silenceRemovedSignal/(max(silenceRemovedSignal)),'Color',[1.0
   0.0 0.0]); grid on; clc;
```

Comment: Could you please describe what you want to implement? What should the timer do?

Comment: text1 will handles timer counting. text1 will show the number(like stopwatch) when pushbutton2 is pressed and (stopwatch) will stop counting in text1 when processes are finished

Comment: The problem you ask about can be potentially big. So to be able to narrow the problem, what is the exact problem you have? By that I mean more specific issue like errors, warnings, nothing happens, ... and so on.

Comment: could you show me how to timer start counting when button pressed and show the counting on static text?

Comment: @EdyPrasetyo: Then you should use `timeit` or `tic` `toc`, not `timer`

Comment: @Daniel thanks a lot Daniel i use tic toc that you recomended and it works like a charm